# Deserialization of a Spark model causes "Spark exception : Failed to get broadcast_40_piece0 of broadcast_40"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, deserialization, apache-spark-ml

I am building a Text classifier pipeline in spark ml with the following stages:
Ngram, Vectorizer, IDF, Logistic regression.
Since we're not using a distributed file system I've to save the generated model on the file system by deserializing the model as a java/scala object. (Spark's default model persistence doesn't work on a cluster without a distributed FS).

For predictions, I'm reading in that serialized model file and using that on a dataset.But I keep getting the following errors/exceptions in that prediction process.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_40_piece0 of broadcast_40
...
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$8: (array<string>) => vector)
...
ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$8: (array<string>) => vector)
```

...

I've filtered the full stack trace as I thought it is not needed. "Failed to get the broadcast piece" comes a couple of times as spark retries it. And particularly, the `udf` error `(array<string>) => vector)` might be the Vectorization stage that I've in my model but I can't be sure.

I didn't find anything similar online regarding this. So far, I have done the following with no luck.

- I tried saving the model the usual spark way (with model.save) on a single node and I was able to run the predictions fine showing that the code is fine.
- In order to make sure that the model is getting properly serialized, I created a CustomModel class that extends serializable with the pipeline model as a parameter. It is still giving the same issue

I know that this question is long now but any ideas on how this can be fixed are appreciated. Any ideas on getting around this issue of saving the model without having a DFS are also welcome.

EDIT:
The code I am using to save and read the model is as follows:

```
// Model creating & saving
val cvModel: PipelineModel =  cv.fit(training).bestModel.asInstanceOf[PipelineModel]
val model = new Model(cvModel)
val fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("model.model")
val outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream)
outputStream.writeObject(model)
outputStream.close()
fileOutputStream.close()
```

Where `Model` is a class that extends `Serializable`

class Model(val model: PipelineModel) extends Serializable

And then for reading the model back

```
// Deserializing the model
val fileInputStream: FileInputStream = new FileInputStream("model.model")
val objectInputStream: ObjectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream)
val model: predictive.Model = objectInputStream.readObject.asInstanceOf[predictive.Model]
fileInputStream.close()
objectInputStream.close()
val pipelineModel = model.model
```

After I have the model deserialized, I predict on a dataset by calling the `transform` method.

```
model.transform(dataset)
```

Comment: Can you show us some of your code? Do you have broadcast variables? There's [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5594) open Spark issue.

Comment: @hoyland I've added the code I've used to serialize and deserialize the model. The code is the standard way to serialize and deserialize and there are no errors in that. And no, I'm not using broadcast variables anywhere. Once I've the model I just call `transform` on the dataset for predictions and I get these errors.

Comment: I apologize for asking a really basic question, but are you sure that the problem is the model and not the dataset you are trying to give it?  Lazy transformations on the dataset will be deferred until your `transform`.

Comment: @JoePallas It can't be the dataset because I'm able to get the full pipeline running if I do the usual `model.save` and `model.load`. But I'm having this issue only when I serialize and deserialize it myself.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39208789/5061485